# Proof verification: $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ convex implies $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists

Tags: limits, analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function, prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists.

My proof: since $f$ is convex in the interval $\mathbb{R}$, for any given $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ the difference quotient $R(x;x_0)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ is an increasing function of $x$. So, in particular, $R(x;0)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ is an increasing function of $x$.

Hence, for the theorem that the limit of increasing functions exists, it exists the limit:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$
Since:
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{f(0)}{x}$$
With $f(0)/x\to0$ as $x \to \infty$ and existing $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$, the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ must exist as well.

Is this correct? I am unsure about what I said in my last paragraph. I tried to prove it in this way: assume $f,g,h$ are functions such that $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ and such that $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x \to x_0} h(x)$ exists finite. Then $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)$ exists. Assume by contradiction that $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)$ doesn't exist, since $g(x)=f(x)-h(x)$ this means that $\lim_{x \to x_0} [f(x)-h(x)]$ doesn't exist, but this contradicts the fact that in these hypotheses it is $\lim_{x \to x_0} [f(x)-h(x)]=\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)-\lim_{x \to x_0} h(x)$ and the latter limits both exist (because the fact that the limit of $h$ is finite avoids indeterminate form).

Comment: Your proof is fine. It must be emphasized that the limit need not be finite, as in the case of $f(x)=x^{2}$.